# Django Admin: Why does my model name have a space after underscore?

Tags: django

My Model:

```
class Venue_Event(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I go into the admin UI, I see a space after the underscore. Any idea why?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYPeG.png)

Comment: Because you're going against Python conventions; there are ways to customize the labelling in Django, but you should simply use `class VenueEvent` instead.

Comment: Ah. I see. I guess django automatically puts a space in front of any capitalized letter in the model name?

Answer (score 2):

If you'd like, you can change the name of how your model displays in the `Meta` like so:

```
class Venue_Event(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(Profile, db_index=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Venue Event'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Venue Events'
```